# Splunk command to check if current search is greater than x% of previous search

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula, splunk-calculation

I want to know how to write search query in Splunk in order to check if the current search is greater than 20% of previous search. I am getting events on a particular count every 10 min. I want to check if my current count (for the last 10 min) is greater than 20% of my previous count(for the last 20 min). I need to use subsearch to make the comparison. But not getting result though. Can anyone help ?

Comment: What does your data look like? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest saving the search results to a summary index.  Then you can a separate search process the summary index looking for instances where the result is 120% of the previous result.

To save your search results to a summary index, add `| collect <summary>` to your existing search.  `<summary>` is the name of an existing index that will receive the search results.

The search that will process the summary can use the `streamstats` command to process events.

```
index=summary 
`comment("Change 'head' to 'tail' if the events are in reverse order")`
| head 2
`comment("Get the difference between the current value and the previous one")`
| streamstats range(foo) as diff
`comment("We don't know the previous value of foo so we need to work 'backward' to see if the current value is too big")`
| where (foo - diff) > (foo * 0.833)
```